# Gnome classic split screen plugin

Tags: compiz, screen, gnome-classic, mutter, split

How do i get Gnome classic to have a split screen? I want it to be like it is in Unity where if i drag something to the side it maximizes its size to cover just half the screen, and then drag something to the side to i do the same on the other side of the screen. I like Gnome classic a lot more than Unity but i like that feature of Unity.

I am on a Ubuntu 11.10
I am on a HP laptop with 3 GB of ram and 2.7 dual core prossesser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search for other solutions, the keywords 'aero snap' might help you. This is how it's called in Windows 7 and many users and developers try to copy it from there.

I used the following two solutions, but I haven't tested them yet on 11.10 and I didn't test the third one at all. The biggest disadvage with all solutions I've found so far: there is no easy way to get the windows back to their original size and position.

### Compiz grid

You'll need the package `compiz-fusion-plugins-extra`. Install it using the package manager or using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
```

Then open the CompizConfig Settings Manager and search for *grid* and enable this plugin. You can then place the active window to the left half

### Compiz command

Compiz commands allow you to define custom commands executed based on specific bindings such as moving a window to an edge of the screen. Detailed instructions are available [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/11/get-aero-snap-in-ubuntu/).

### gTile in Gnome 3

Use this gnome 3 [gTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/) extension to resize and place your windows on a grid. This extension was inspired by Divvy for Mac OS, so you can watch [this video](http://vimeo.com/17934894) to get an idea of how it's working.

Answer (score 0):

The **snap** plugin, a plugin of compiz, which is the used window manager in Unity. *Gnome classic* AKA *Gnome Shell* doesn't use *compiz* but *mutter* which is the predecessor of metacity in Gnome/GTK3.
And mutter **yet** does not have this plugin AFAIK.
So maybe stick with Unity? It's not that bad ;-)

Comment: This does work in Gnome Shell. Top edge gives full screen, left and right gives half screen.

Comment: i want the drop down menu interface. I don't like the dock in unity, its okay other wise. The dock gets in the way at times, and i like the simplicity of the menus.

Comment: the plug in is active but, isnt working, i have this type of radom glitches sometimes and if i restart they go away, my computer is telling me its been on to long i guess, still wish i could make them stop